# Properly placing AWS credentials for Jenkins/Packer Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, github, packer

I'm needing to have Packer build an image in AWS. The Packer template will be stored in a Github repository and deployed using Jenkins.

Where would I specify my AWS Access and Secret Keys? I can't put them in the JSON template in Github (that'd be bad) :(

Do I configure my access keys using the AWS cli on the Jenkins server or can I specify my in the Jenkins Packer Plugin?

Comment: What exactly are the credentials for? For what resourse? For what purpose? This information will impact the proper credential storage method.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use a worker node with an *instance role* that have the right permissions to run Packer. The second best is to use [Jenkins secrets plugin](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) to store the secrets and set them as environment variables in your Packer build job.

Comment: Thank you; something I never considered.

Answer (score 0):

I'll investigate using the Jenkins secrets plugin. In the interim, I am able to specify the secret key and access key under the, "Additional Parameters" field as shown. The Packer template is retained within Github which Jenkins fetches when job runs. Did not use Github Pull plugin due to security concerns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYVxy.png)

Answer (score 0):

As Rickard answered, it is better to use the Instance Role. The way we have implemented is, we have a role called "PackerRole" with necessary permissions that gets used by packer.  In the packer.json, refer the role as "iam_instance_profile": "PackerRole".

Now create a separate role called "JenkinsRole"( whatever name suits you which will be used by the Jenkins node), that has an inline policy to pass "PackerRole".

{
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:passrole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1234567:role/PackerEc2Role"
        }